# jasmine login test using ngrx effect Angular5

Tags: angular, jasmine, ngrx

I'm testing a login effects service using jasmine with marbles

It's fairly, straightforward; the user sends login info (email and password)
via the store payload to the effect

the api endpoint which check credentials, responds with a token that is decoded to be used as a constructor parameter for the LoginSuccess class, within the effects service.

I've gotten it working, however, I'm finding that the test reaches out to the "real" effects service and returns an object "userState".

This object I am mocking in the test also (along with using `createSpyObj` for the  authService, which works)

If the objects don't match (including having matching tokens, which I had to copy from a real login) the test fails, I'm a little lost on this one if someone could give some pointers

The effects file:

```
export class LoginEffects {
  constructor(private actions$: Actions,
              private authService: AuthService,
              private router: Router) {}

@Effect() login$: Observable<any> = this.actions$
    .pipe(
      ofType<LogIn>(LOGIN),
      mergeMap(action => {
      return this.authService.login(action.payload.email, action.payload.password)
      .pipe(
        map((data)=> {
           //Decode the returned jwt
          let decodedData = jwt_decode(data.token);
          //userState is being mocked in test as well
          let userState:loginReducer.State = {
            isAuthenticated: true,
            token:data.token,
            name:decodedData.name
          }
          console.log(userState)
         return new LoginSuccess(userState)
        }),
        catchError((error) => {
            return Observable.of(new LogInFailure({ error: error }));
          })
      )
    }),

  )
}
```

test file:

```
import { LoginEffects } from "./login.effects";
import { TestBed, fakeAsync } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { provideMockActions } from '@ngrx/effects/testing';
import {of} from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { cold } from 'jasmine-marbles';
import { AuthService } from "../../../services/auth.service";
import {RouterTestingModule} from "@angular/router/testing";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import * as EffectsAction from '../actions/login.actions';
import { StoreModule} from "@ngrx/store";
import { reducers } from "../../../reducers";

describe('LoginEffects', () => {
   let effects, authService;
  let actions$: Observable<any>;
    beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {})
      ],
      providers: [
        LoginEffects,  
        {
          provide: AuthService,
          useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('authService', ['login'])
        },
        provideMockActions(() => actions$)
      ]
    }));
    beforeEach(() => {
      effects = TestBed.get(LoginEffects);
      authService = TestBed.get(AuthService);
    });

    describe('Effects', () => {
      it('should return response from server', () => {
        // service = TestBed.get(AuthService);
        const payloadInfo = {email: 'test@reflections.co.uk', password:'password'}
        const userState = {
          isAuthenticated: true,
          //copied token     token:'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiTHVrZSIsImlhdCI6MTUzMTQwMTgyOSwiZXhwIjoxNTMxNDAzMDI5LCJzdWIiOiI1OWM3ODA4YzE3Y2UzZTc1ODU4M2RjOWEifQ.Kr6NfLc9mgz8_O6wlnAo1E4jTSE0Q3tB4vqwIQOVWcasSm8MlPPmvx1WqLkRkKx1r_Rba0bjGIQ7iypZNW-XJEqr25GCnL3gparJap5CWqd_4dea48cNbcM_Km5cCkQ746IBVt2uarrqxBMvp4HAp2mP6E-A1XuV04p6VcnincGxwCW5lTQNFySKSVZ-cOOLOdlyhYhsvvPvu-f7J3W0poqniEJICkFaVnweBWogDUonqe_48z_eRauLkIdeLBPj3PO67XVgIGe423P15ZXXmmrXNFT4iGsCSfG_MJdljgTaZl65UcD_bu8wRkYTd4Vh0qBIuULyem4YDolaFMhcKg',
              name:'Luke'
        }
     const action = new EffectsAction.LogIn({type:'LOGIN', payload:payloadInfo});
        const result = new EffectsAction.LoginSuccess(userState)

        actions$ = of(action);
        const response = cold( 'a', {a : userState})
        const expected = cold( 'b', {b : result})
        authService.login.and.returnValue(response);
        console.log(expected)
        expect(effects.login$).toBeObservable(expected);
      });

    });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it was to do with decoding the response sent from the authService
And assigning the data to properties of the userState:

```
  //Decode the returned jwt
     console.log(data)//This would be my mockdetails
      let decodedData = jwt_decode(data.token);
      console.log(decodedData)//This would have the details from logged in user
      let userState:loginReducer.State = {
        isAuthenticated: true,
        token:data.token,
        name:decodedData.name//this is from logged in user throws error
      }
console.log(userState)//This would have the details from logged in user
```

What this seemed to be doing was; extracting the real logged in user info into memory when decoding and applying to the userState object

I saw that I didn't need to decode to get the username I could just grab it from the returned object:

```
map((data)=> {
 let userState:loginReducer.State = {
    isAuthenticated: true,
    token:data.token,
    name:data.name
  }
})
```

So it works but I couldn't work out what to do if I had to decode?